# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied on Windows 10 (Oracle 12.2.0.1.0)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm using DBeaver to create a connection, but I'm seeing this error
[image]
Although I can connect with sys (as sysdba).
I tried to set sec_case_sensitive_logon=false and reset the password, it didn't help.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you can connect as SYS, then check whether user TEST exists in the TW database. If so, change its password and try again. Match letter case for both username and password (regardless of settings you might be setting, trying to fix the problem).

Comment: The user exist. I changed the password several times, but it didn't help.

Comment: I was using Oracle 12.2, and it didn't work. I removed it and installed 12.1, now it's working. I'm not sure what was the issue.